# Does Google App Engine allow 3rd party web service access?

Tags: java, web-services, google-app-engine

I'm trying to write a Java app in GAE that consumes some 3rd party web services, but when I generate the client from the WSDL files, I get the following error -

java.rmi.Remote is not supported by Google App Engine's Java runtime environment

Is there a work-around for this or is it simply not possible on GAE ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jva.rmi.Remote is not supported in the GAE framework

the urlfetch is the standard library to do this.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/